# Adding a new column to a dataframe based on groupby.sum() results

Tags: python, pandas

I need some help with a pandas issue.

So I have the next dataframe:

```
Timestamp      group    total_per_group
2018-01-01      1             5
2018-01-01      0             1
2018-02-01      0             7
2018-03-01      1             0
2018-03-01      0             4
2018-04-01      1             2
2018-04-01      0             1
2018-05-01      1             4
2018-06-01      1             5
2018-06-01      0             2
```

In which the column `total_per_group` indicates the total puntuation for either group 1 or group 0 in the month indicated by timestamp (there can be only one group in a given timestamp, check for example, 2018-02-01, in which we only have group 0).

I want to add a new column called `total` in which i have the total punctuation earned by the two groups in a month given by timestamp.
It would look like the following:

```
Timestamp      group    total_per_group      total
2018-01-01      1             5                6
2018-01-01      0             1                6
2018-02-01      0             7                7
2018-03-01      1             0                4
2018-03-01      0             4                4
2018-04-01      1             2                3
2018-04-01      0             1                3
2018-05-01      1             4                4
2018-06-01      1             5                7
2018-06-01      0             2                7
```

I've tried to do a groupby using the timestamp column, but the problem is that I want to add the column to the original dataframe, and it gives me an output with 6 rows (one per timestamp).

Any help on this issue would be great.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: `df['total'] = df.groupby(by=['Timestamp'])['total_per_group'].transform(sum)`

Comment: Is the day info always the same @HRDSL?